# How to know how many concurrent users jMeter can start?

Tags: jmeter

There is a place in jMeter where you can specify the number of users you want to start concurrently. I assume you can't put a number where it exceeds the limitation on your hardware & OS.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html

> If you set the value to 0, then JMeter will immediately start all of your users.

But given a specific hardware and OS, let say windows 7, i5 CPU, 8GB RAM. How do I know or calculate the number of users I can put to start all the users concurrently? Although I can trial & error to find out the numbers, I hoping if there is a way to pre-calculate it.

Comment: To clarify my question:
What I am trying to figure out here is let say I put number of threads = 500, and ramp-up time = 0. How do I know jMeter actually starts all 500 threads in zero seconds. Because I am sure each thread will take certain amount of hardware resources (e.g. memory, CPU). Because I assume if hardware is busy, some of the threads might not start immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ramp-up time` is not really important except for special cases, so they recommend in the same paragraph to keep it at the default value of 1 sec, which means all threads you enter in the `number of threads` field will be started within 1 second. Also, for the local OS it doesn't matter at all if you start all threads at once or with a `ramp-up time`, the limiting factor will be the number of threads alone.

How large you can select the `number of threads` value on the client machine is dependend on many factors and you have to test it yourself, but since the purpose of JMeter is to see how your server handles X concurrent connections, I assume in many cases the server or the network connection to the server will be the limiting factor, not the local machine itself.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. What I am trying to figure out here is let say I put number of threads = 500, and ramp-up time = 0. How do I know jMeter actually starts all 500 threads in zero seconds. Because I am sure each thread will take certain amount of hardware resources (e.g. memory, CPU). Because I assume if hardware is busy, some of the threads might not start immediately?

Comment: I am sure here is no general metric to calculate this, but I doubt this will be relevant at all, except you have a very large number of threads to start and you really need an instant ramp-up, but why would you?

Comment: I am hoping to test how the server can handle sudden surge of traffic. But the test might not be accurate if I am not sure if jMeter can or cannot start X number of concurrent users within 0 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

To check all threads were started simultaneously use [listeners](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65145-jmeter-2-6-listeners). For instance [View result in table](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_in_Table), see 'Start time' column